# Optimal way to transfer filtered documents from a Mongo collection to another (in nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to filter a big MongoDB collection (today, 3500000 docs, tomorrow, a lot more...), and transfer some of its content to an empty collection. Here is my ES6 naive approach:

```js
await col_target.drop();
const cursor = await col_source.find();

while (await cursor.hasNext()) {
  const doc = await cursor.next();
  
  // the filter is and array of regular expressions
  if (!regex.map(_ => new RegExp(_, 'imu').test(doc.rawJson.text)).reduce((a, b) => a || b)) continue;
  
  await col_target.insertOne(prepareTweet(doc));
}

await db.close();
```

I have the feeling this is not optimal, because the find & insert operations should be parallelized. But I don't really know how to do that. Could someone provide me advice on how to improve my code?

Comment: It's not really clear. Could you provide sample documents, and explain a little bit which ones you wnat to transfer ?

Comment: Each and every document has the same structure:
- the Mongo _id field
- a rawJson field, which holds a tweet given by Twitter stream API.

I want to filter tweets from the source collection according to their text, and store them to the target collection.

However, I do not see how the structure of my documents is related to my question, which is more about the "flow" of the program :)

Comment: And my question would be the same if the filter line is: if(Math.random() < 0.5) continue; ;)

Answer (score 1):

you should do this in a single query, it would be way faster

```
db.col_source.aggregate([
    {$match: {rawJson: /someRegex/gi }},
    {$out: "col_target"}
])
```

of course, don't forget to create a [**text index**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/) on `rawJson` field

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try to implement it, indeed, my code is slow because of the js "test"... I could make a better use of the MongoDB engine.

Comment: OK, done. Wonderful perf improvement! Thanks again felix.